# magento-patches: Permission denied

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.3

Magento 2.4.3

Installed quality-patches via

> composer require magento/quality-patches

Trying to apply a patch via

> ./vendor/bin/magento-patches apply MDVA-40311

Getting error:

> ./vendor/bin/magento-patches: line 14: /xxxxxxxx/vendor/magento/magento-cloud-patches/bin/magento-patches: Permission denied

p.s. ./bin/magento works no problem

Comment: seems like this is folder permission issue

Answer (score 1):

Following may do:

```
chmod +x ./vendor/magento/magento-cloud-patches/bin/magento-patches
./vendor/bin/magento-patches apply MDVA-40311  
chmod -x ./vendor/magento/magento-cloud-patches/bin/magento-patches
```